# Problems granting read / write permission to 'NT AUTHORITY \ NetworkService' when registering Redis Sentinel as a service in Windows

Tags: redis

Problems granting read / write permission to 'NT AUTHORITY \ NetworkService' when registering Redis Sentinel as a service in Windows

[image]

The service is registered but not executed.
I assume that the problem is caused by the fact that the NetworkService is not authorized to read and write the pid file.
So, as shown in the image below, the user account has administrator privileges along with net service permissions in the folder
[image]

But the problem is still happening. What is wrong with the issue of permissions?
In case you don't know, I'm writing down the conf file setting.

```
port 11425
daemonize yes
pidfile "redis-sentinel-11425.pid"
logfile ""
dir "C:\\program files\\redis\\tmp"
sentinel monitor mymaster 127.0.0.1 10425 2
sentinel config-epoch mymaster 2
sentinel leader-epoch mymaster 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. The reason the service is not running is not related to permissions The problem with that is that I entered the command incorrectly. The last option in the command is -sentinel, but the correct answer is --sentinel